# how to post data input in div jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jquery and php. I want sent data using jQuery's method `$.ajax`. I have some sample HTML code. I don't want use the tag `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

```
<div class="body-post">
    <input name="id" type="text" value=""/>
    <ul>
       <li>
            <input name="title[]" type="text" value=""/>
            <input name="detail[]" type="text" value=""/>
            <input name="link-target[]" type="checkbox" value="0"/>
       </li>
       <li>
            <input name="title[]" type="text" value=""/>
            <input name="detail[]" type="text" value=""/>
            <input name="link-target[]" type="checkbox" value="0"/>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I make an ajax call cotaining data of inputs in the Div.
I want post a data array like this:

```
array
{
   [id] => 1,
   [title] => array
       [
          [0] => title 1,
          [1] => title 2,             
       ],
   [detail]  =>array 
       [
          [0] => detail 1,
          [1] => detail 2, 
       ]
   [link-tagert]  =>array 
       [
          [0] => 0,
          [1] => 1, 
       ]
}
```

**updated** 
thanks ***Mark Eriksson*** help me. 
i want ask more. when i add input type checked default value 0, if checked value 1 . I want if i unchecked input  result link-tagert=0;

Comment: `$.serialize()` look up the jQuery docs for that

Comment: Also check `$.serialize()` vs `$.serializeArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the comments (@Mark Eriksson)

Use `$.serialize()` [jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

It would seem that $.serialize() does not work with the div. So either add a form or specifically select all the inputs.

HTML:

```
<div id="form" class="body-post">
    <input name="id" type="text" value=""/>
    <ul>
       <li>
            <input name="title[]" type="text" value=""/>
            <input name="detail[]" type="text" value=""/>
       </li>
       <li>
            <input name="title[]" type="text" value=""/>
            <input name="detail[]" type="text" value=""/>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input').on('blur', function(){
  console.log($('input').serialize())
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7gu1cs98/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want send data, use this for a POST send

```
// jQuery
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: <url>,
  data: <data>
});

// or just in JavaScript (without jQuery)
var post = new XMLHttpRequest();
post.open("POST", <url>, true);
post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
post.send(<data>);
```

and this for a GET send

```
// jQuery
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: <url>,
  data: <data>
});

// or just in JavaScript (without jQuery)
var get = new XMLHttpRequest();
get.open("GET", <url>, true);
get.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
get.send(<data>);
```

To aliment `<data>` you could use some:

```
// jQuery
{
    "var1": $(".input1").val(),
    "var2": $(".input1").val()
}

// or just in JavaScript (without jQuery)
{
    "var1": document.getElementsByClassName("input1")[0].value,
    "var2": document.getElementsByClassName("input2")[0].value
}
```

---

But if you want « Response » after your GET/POST use following:

```
// jQuery
function request(url, next) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
          next(null, response);
        },
        error: function() {
          next(new Error("There was a connection error of some sort."));
        }
    });
}
request(<url>, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    response;
});

// or just in JavaScript (without jQuery)
function request(url, next) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
    request.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (request.status < 200 && request.status >= 400) {
            return next(new Error("We reached our target server, but it returned an error."));
        }
        next(null, request.responseText);
    });
    request.addEventListener("error", function () {
        return next(new Error("There was a connection error of some sort."));
    });
}
request(>url>, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    response;
});
```